# I'm trying to output password statuses for RedHat. Is there an equivalent of "password -s" in RedHat?

Tags: rhel, solaris, password

I'm trying to output password statuses for RedHat.

For my Solaris machine, I was able to run:

```
for i in `more shadow | awk -F: '{print $1}'`; do passwd -s $i; done
```

And that gave me password statuses for all accounts - Ex. PS, UN, UL, etc.

Is there an equivalent of "password -s" to show password statuses for RedHat?

Answer (score 3):

I only have a SuSE machine handy, so take this with a pinch of salt, but it's probably the `-S` switch to `passwd`:

> `-S`, `--status`
>
> Display account status information. The status information consists of 7 fields. The first field
>       is the user's login name. The second field indicates if the user account has a locked password
>              (L), has no password (NP), or has a usable password (P). The third field gives the date of the
>              last password change. The next four fields are the minimum age, maximum age, warning period, and
>              inactivity period for the password. These ages are expressed in days.

[This man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/passwd/) suggests it might only be available to root on CentOS/RedHat; on SuSE, you can also run `passwd --status` to find out about your own account.

Comment: Oh, nice, I'll read through this and give it another whirl. I appreciate it

Comment: on RHEL7/CentOS7 it `passwd --status <username>` is how the command works.